# Paypal charges a tax while transferring money from account to account - is this Riba?

Tags: riba

Paypal charges a tax when you transfer money from one account to another. I am confused on whether is this Riba or not. If it is, what if I change the currency while transferring?

Comment: AFAIK, at least, Paypal does not label that fee as an interest. They call it _transaction [handling] fee_.

Comment: No it is not . It is a fee. You are using their service which itself isn't free for them. They   have the rights to take a fee. That is why you in the first place wanted their service, because it works good and helps you.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. It's the price you pay in exchange of a service. Riba is borrowing an amount of money, and return it after in a bigger amount according to the delay.